# "kotlin-noarg" plugin don't work in Realm

Tags: android, realm, kotlin

"kotlin-allopen" plugin work but "kotlin-noarg" plugin don't work.
How can I do?

Below is the code.

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
    }
}
apply plugin: "kotlin-allopen"
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"

allOpen {
    annotation("sample.AllOpen")
}
noArg {
    annotation("sample.NoArg")
    invokeInitializers = true
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

NoArg.kt

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class NoArg
```

MyApplication.kt

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Realm.init(this)
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
```

SampleEntity.kt

```
@NoArg
@AllOpen
@RealmClass
data class SampleEntity(var sample: String?) : RealmModel
```

when build, the following error was displayed.`Class "SampleEntity" must declare a public constructor with no arguments if it contains custom constructors.`

Does it work with realm?

Answer (score 6):

This is intended behaviour. From the documentation: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin

> The generated constructor is synthetic so it can’t be directly called
>   from Java or Kotlin, but it can be called using reflection

Comment: Than you. I overlooked that.  
The following code work. ```val entity = SampleEntity::class.java.newInstance()```

Comment: You should annotate SampleEntity with `@NoArg`, or add `@RealmClass` to the noArg config

Comment: It looks like Realm specifically needs a `public` no-args constructor when it checks via this class https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/9bef1333d160ac1dbc441a12f6dd2704bbe7a774/realm/realm-annotations-processor/src/main/java/io/realm/processor/Utils.java (see `isDefaultConstructor`), which would mean the synthetic constructor wouldn't work. Note, Kotlin will generate a public no-arg constructor if every parameter in the constructor has a default value.

Comment: Is it possible to run no-arg before realm-annotations-processor is called?
Since ```isDefaultConstructor``` determines whether it is ```Public``` by reflection, it seems possible if the order changes

Comment: It won't be possible - the reason the no-args constructor created by kotlin-noargs can only be called via reflection is because it's effectively private, so changing the order the annotation processors run will not make a difference.

Comment: @ko2ic `SampleEntity::class.java.newInstance()` was deprecated since Java 9.
You can use this `SampleEntity::class.java.getConstructor().newInstance()`.