# Kotlin Realm: Class must declare a public constructor with no arguments if it contains custom constructors

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I'm creating a **Realm** object in **Kotlin**.

**Realm Object:**

```
open class PurposeModel(var _id: Long?,
                        var purposeEn: String?,
                        var purposeAr: String?) : RealmObject()
```

When I compile the above code I'm getting this error:

```
error: Class "PurposeModel" must declare a public constructor with no arguments if it contains custom constructors.
```

I can't find any question related to this in Kotlin. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

To clear this error you have to assign default values to properties.

Change the Realm Object like this:

```
open class PurposeModel(
    var _id: Long? = 0,
    var purposeEn: String? = null,
    var purposeAr: String? = null
) : RealmObject()
```

Now it will compile.

**Reason:**

> When the default value not assigned it will become the parameters of
>   the constructor, Realm need a public constructor with no arguments.
>   When the default value assigned, it will become the properties of the
>   class. So you will get empty constructor by default and clean code.

Comment: Good one here; helped

Comment: This does not work in new version of the Realm Kotlin SDK

Comment: @AbolfazlAbbasi the same. Did You find the solution? I am on Realm Kotlin SDK 1.13.0.

Answer (score 7):

That's why I prefer to define them like this

```
open class PurposeModel : RealmObject() {
    @field:PrimaryKey
    var id: Long? = null
    var purposeEn: String? = null
    var purposeAr: String? = null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Realm on my Ktor server and you need to provide an empty constructor with default values.

```
@Serializable
class User(
    val id: String,
    var email: String,
    var hashedPass: ByteArray,
) : RealmObject {
    constructor() : this(
        id = ObjectId.create().toString(),
        email = "",
        hashedPass = byteArrayOf()
    ) // Empty constructor for Realm
}
```

Without it, I was getting and error:

```
[Realm] Cannot find primary zero arg constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

**Error:**

_id, purposeEn, purposeAr not initialized

**Solution**

```
open class PurposeModel(
var _id: Long? = 0,
var purposeEn: String? = "",
var purposeAr: String? = ""
) : RealmObject()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was adding the `abstract` keyword, below is my working code,

```kotlin
@Log4j2
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal abstract class ItemsManagementControllerTest(
    private val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(
        ItemsManagementControllerTest::class.java
    ) as Logger,
    private var mvc: MockMvc? = null,
    @InjectMocks private val itemsManagementController: ItemsManagementController? = null,
    @Mock private val itemRepository: ItemRepository? = null
) {
```

Removing the `abstract` keywords fails the test cases in the class. I honestly do not understand why at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the [Kotlin no-arg plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#no-arg-compiler-plugin) which generates a no-arg constructor for you.

Comment: It seems that is not possible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45770049/4777865), if it is possible, please, could you provide a more complete answer?

Comment: Hi, @GabrielDeOliveiraRohden. I don't know how Realm works internally (why it needs noarg constructor). When writing an answer, I assumed it works similarly to Hibernate (which is JavaEE ORM), which constructs entities using a no-arg constructor. I used the no-arg plugin with Hibernate in my project and it worked well. Although, I haven't tried with Realm.